# How to see bundles and back projecting points of different colors?

Tags: video, tracking

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking):

> **Bundles** makes sense after solving the movie clip, and it works in the following way: the solved position of each track gets projected
>   back to the movie clip and **displayed as a small point**. The **color of
>   the point depends** on the distance between the projected coordinate and
>   the original coordinate: if they are close enough, the **point is green**,
>   otherwise **it'll be red**. This helps to find tracks which weren't solved
>   nicely and need to be tweaked.

I am solving the scene and see nothing similar to what's described:

[image]

Points are displayed not as points, but as squares, blue means before in time, red means after in time. Yellow or white means selected point.

Where is something green?

Comment: I might be mis-interpreting something here, but those look green and red to me.. Here's an [example image](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=73367).

Comment: @gandalf3 yes the boxes will change color too according to the reprojection error. But I believe the OP is asking about the 3D markers, those show up as colored dots showing the actual location of the solved tracker.

Comment: @gandalf3 but this is different. red rectangles mean that tracks are exist on other frames, not on current frame; and dirty green rectangles denote tracks on current frame; no any variation according to description

Answer (score 6):

Those red and green colored points are available **only after you have successfully solved** the scene.

To make them visible, enable the overlay in clip display > Marker Display > 3D markers

[image]

(for 2.79  enable **3D Markers** on the Marker Display Tab.)

[image]

The dots show the difference between the tracker and where blender is actually laying the points in 3D space. It is a visual reference to help you identify problems and further refine your track to get a better camera solve. The colors reflect to the ["reprojection error"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reprojection_error) If the rerpojected points are close to the original tracker they will show green,

[image]

Otherwise they will be red. Notice how the dots are away from where the tracker is.

[image]

Sometimes you can make the reprojected points fall closer to the original trackers by moving the optical center on the camera presets .
[image]

But if your reprojection errors are too high you might be dealing with errors on the focal lenght, the optical center or the radial distortion coefficients. So solve the scene again using those options in the refine section.

For more info on the last step see:

[How to determine lens undistortion values for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking)